# How to create double-lined shapes in MS Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

All I could see are single lined shapes. Tried in properties, could not find it.

How do I draw double lined shapes. For ex: Double lined rectangles, ovals, diamonds, lines.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by creating a custom line pattern and then using that line pattern on the shapes where you want the double lines. Where the line pattern looks like this:

[image]

The full set of steps is a bit involved and involves some nuances that are hard to describe in text, so I have put the instructions and a link to a screencast showing exactly how this is done below:

http://viziblr.com/news/2011/10/4/visio-creating-double-lined-shapes.html

I'd recommend starting by watching the screencast first, because then you'll get a quick overall understanding of the process.